# Set a geolocation to null

Tags: apex, geolocation

I have a trigger as:

```
trigger GeoCodeContact on Contact (after update)
{
    if (Trigger.new[it].MailingStreet != null &&
        Trigger.new[it].MailingCity != null &&
        Trigger.new[it].MailingCountry != null) {
        // some stuff here
    } esle {
        for(Integer it = 0; it < Trigger.new.size(); it++) {
            if (Trigger.new[it].MailingStreet != Trigger.old[it].MailingStreet ||
                Trigger.new[it].MailingCity != Trigger.old[it].MailingCity ||
                Trigger.new[it].MailingCountry != Trigger.old[it].MailingCountry) {
                // I come here when the address have change to a null value
                Contact cont = [ SELECT Id, Adresse_geocodee__c FROM Contact WHERE Id = :Trigger.new[it].Id ];
                cont.Adresse_geocodee__latitude__s = null;
                cont.Adresse_geocodee__longitude__s = null;
                System.debug('Contact update: ' + cont);
                update cont;
                cont = [ SELECT Id, Adresse_geocodee__c FROM Contact WHERE Id = :Trigger.new[it].Id ];
                System.debug('Contact after update: ' + cont);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My test look like:

```
    @IsTest
    private static void GeoCodeContact_Update_NoAddress_Trigger_Test()
    {
    Account compte = new Account(Name = 'TEST');
    insert compte;
    Contact cont = new Contact(
        LastName = 'Test', AccountId = compte.Id, Statut__c = 'R+',
        MailingStreet = 'Street',
        MailingCity = 'City',
        MailingCountry = 'Country',
        MailingPostalCode = '000'
    );
    test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockImpl());
    test.startTest();
    insert cont;
    cont.MailingStreet = '';
    cont.MailingCity = '';
    cont.MailingCountry = '';
    cont.MailingPostalCode = '';
    update cont;
    test.stopTest();

    cont = [ SELECT Id, Adresse_geocodee__c FROM Contact WHERE Id = :cont.Id ];
    System.assertEquals(null, cont.Adresse_geocodee__c);
}
```

When I run the test the value of `cont.Adresse_geocodee__c` isn't set tu `null`, but with the debug in the trigger I see the value `cont.Adresse_geocodee__c` is set to `null`at the end. I don't understand why at the end of te trigger the value of geocode is set to `null` (as I wan't) but In the test the value isn't...

Comment: I see that you have a "MockImpl" class instance for an Http callout. If you have an asynchronous process that is supposed to fill in those fields, then it is possible that the implementation is setting those fields when `Test.stopTest()` is called (that's usually when async proceses are run in test cases).

Comment: your trigger's if statement will always be true because your testmethod is setting address values to empty string which is not the same as NULL